# Compare MigraDoc Table Cell with String

Tags: c#, migradoc

I have a MigraDoc `Table` for my PDF document. There are multiple `Row` objects with a person ID, name, firstname and so on. Now I would like to compare the person ID from the table with a string, like:

```
if (table.Rows[i][10].ToString() == Person.ID && table.Rows[i][10].ToString() != "")
{
    //do something
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not go into the query because `table.Rows[i][10].ToString()` is not the correct call.
Is there a way to call the value of the cell?

Comment: have you tried `.Equals` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-compare-strings

Comment: @dimmik The error message "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values" appears at the equals method

Comment: Did you follow the link i gave you ? Can you please post what you have tried

Comment: Try to do the following `var test =table.Rows[i][10].ToString() ` then compare   `if(test == Person.Id)` or the Equals Method

Comment: what data type is `Person.ID` ? is it a string?

Comment: @dimmik I have tested `bool result = String.Equals(table.Rows[i][10], Person.ID)` and `table.Rows[i][10].Equals(playerEvent.Player.PassNumber)`. The `var test =table.Rows[i][10].ToString()` appears the RangeExecption too

Comment: @MongZhu yes it is a string

Comment: And its not working ? Strange... make sure that both of the parameters in the `Equals` method are `strings`

Comment: Try with debug mode and check the value type of `table.Rows[i][10]`

Comment: It's `MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Cell`

Comment: A cell can contain anything: text only, or an image, or even a nested table. There is no `ToString()` you can call for a cell to get the contents. You can call `ToString()` for any object in C#, but sometimes you just get the class name. Cannot harm to look with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but there is no simple way. A cell can contain many document elements. In the most simple case you have a paragraph with a text element. You can get the text from those elements.

Your code fills the cell so your code should know what's in it. Maybe keep an array where you can lookup the ID for e.g. row 5.

Simple workaround: assign the text you put into that cell to the "Tag" member of the cell and use that for comparison. No extra array needed.